# How to declare a string array in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

How can I declare a string array in Groovy? I am trying as below but it is throwing an error

```
def String[] osList = new String[]

No expression for the array constructor call at line:
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_statements. It's either `def`, or the type, but not both.

Comment: I tried even with
String[] osList=new String[] it is throwing the same error

Comment: Arrays have a fixed size. You need to provide it when constructing an array. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_arrays. Why don't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of: welcome to SO!

You have a few options for creating arrays in groovy.

But let's start with what you've done wrong.

```
def String[] osList = new String[]
```

You used both `def` and `String[]` here.

Def is an anonymous type, which means that groovy will figure out which type it is for you.
String[] is the declared type, so what groovy will see here is:

```
String[] String[] osList = new String[]
```

which obviously won't work.

Arrays however need a fixed size, which needs to be given as an argument to the creation of the Array:

```
Type[] arr = new Type[sizeOfArray]
```

in your case if you'd want to have 10 items in the array you would do:

```
String[] osList = new String[10]
```

if you do not know how many Strings you will have, use a List instead. An ArrayList will do for this in most cases:

```
List<String> osList = new ArrayList<>()
```

now you can add items by calling:

```
osList.add("hey!")
```

or using groovy's list-add operator:

```
osList << "hey!"
```

For further issues you should refer to [groovy's official documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html) and see if you can't find the solution yourself!

Comment: I don't think it is the case that our compiler (or runtime) sees `def String[] osList = new String[]` as `String[] String[] osList = new String[]`.  Assuming you specify a size, `def String[] osList = new String[0]` is *not* seen as `String[] String[] osList = new String[0]`.  The former is valid (though non-sensical) but the latter is invalid, and shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 5):

```
​def arr = [] as String[]
```

or

```
String[] arr = [] as String[]
```

This should do it. You can test it and play around in here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Comment: I think if you use either of those approaches, the array will always be empty, and there will be no way to put anything in the array.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is

```
String[] osList = []
assert osList.class.array
assert 'java.lang.String[]' == osList.class.typeName
```

Another question is that this definition is rather useless. This is an immutable zero-length String[] and can be used only as a constant somewhere.